# How to mark a menu item as active for two different routes in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am using the `routerLinkActive` attribute to change the background-color of my menu-items depending on the page that is currently displayed. This is the HTML for my MenuItem component:

```
<div class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
  <my-icon name="{{ iconName }}"></my-icon>
  <a routerLink="{{ routerLink }}">{{ title }}</a>
</div>
```

When using this component, I have to pass in the `routerLink` attribute, such as `/home`.
This works fine with the only issue being that I want the menu-item "Home" to be marked as active when the route is `base_url/home` as well as just `base_url/`. I don't know how to achieve this though.

In my app.module.ts file, I am defining the following routes:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    ...
  ],
```

So, the HomeComponent is displayed initially, but the corresponding menu item is not marked as active.

I guess that one solution could be to simply pass in `/` as the routerLink for my HomeComponent and then add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"` to the MenuItem component. Actually, I have verified that it works. The issue that I have with this solution is, that I would really like the `/home` to show in my URL whenever I am displaying my HomeComponent - just for consistency, it is visible for all other pages after all.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue that I have with this solution is, that I would really like
> the /home to show in my URL whenever I am displaying my HomeComponent

You should use a redirect from default `''` route into `home` route path. Then the menu will work as expected as well as your above requirement to always show the url in the form of `/home`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    ...
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `pathMatch`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  ],
```

[angular routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Route)

by default  path-match strategy is `prefix`, Or for empty paths you can write `full`.